# How to avoid configuration via config?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there some example of how to generate Step with a code, not as configured Bean

```
@Bean
public Step simpleStep(JdbcBatchItemWriter<SomeInputDto> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("simpleStep")
            .<SomeInputDto, SomeOutputDto> chunk(100)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(handler())
            .writer(writer)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

Exactly, I want generate reader and step for each table of my database

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch? What are the input/output of your job?

Comment: Need analyze all tables in db. Input is some data from it. Output some analyze result

Comment: What do you mean by "How to avoid configuration via config?"